# How adapt in wideness Overleaf

Tags: overleaf

I'd like to adapt the PDF at the widthness of Overleaf screen. Yesterday it was possible, but today no. Could Someone explain me why? Was Overleaf edited in these days? How could I back to previous format?
I hope my question is clear
Thank you so much

**First Edit:** I show my problem with this photo: I'd like that the PDF is totally adapted at the read-screen.

[image: Adapt PDF]

Comment: Please ask the Overleaf support.

Comment: Ok, thank you. But where?

Comment: Google for  "overleaf support"

Comment: your question isn't clear but if you mean you want to change the relative widths of the source editor and the pdf viewer simply place your mouse cursor over the cental bar and drag it left or right.

Comment: Or are you wanting the pdf to be wider within its window?  I think that's done by going to the top left of the pdf area, and clicking the `| <-> |` (fit to width).

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!!

Comment: Do you want that I close this question?

Comment: You could alo stry using the setting `\hypersetup{pdfstartview=FitH}`, assuming you are already using the `hyperref` pacakge.

Comment: What strange! Nothing changed...

Comment: @Puck: In case the last comment was meant for me, then the Overleaf pdf viewer seems to ignore the settings in a pdf to fit to width. You should test with/without this option in Adobe Acrobat and for a long page, you should see the pdf open such that it fits the width of the page. BTW, you should use the `@<usedid>` to make sure that the person that you are responding to gets a notification (as I did at the start of the post).

Comment: I solved yesterday my problem, thank you very much anyway